# C - Element of fgets in a new variable

Tags: c, stdin, fgets

I am a beginner in the C language and I'm trying to read the input from a user in the terminal (stdin).I want the user to be able to put as many numbers or characters as he wants until he presses ENTER.

I want to store the second value in a Int variable.

For example the user enters : **45 34 RE 34**

I'm trying to use the

`fgets(input,1024,stdin)`

which gives me an array of characters stored in input, but I need the number after the first space, so **3** and the number after it, **4** in a new variable.

I know it seems pretty easy but I'm having some difficulty doing it, is there an easy code to do that?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, `if(sscanf(input, "%*s%d", &number) == 1) { ... }`

Comment: @WeatherVane is on the right track, but using scanf like that will store `34` in number, as opposed to `3` in one variable and `4` in another.  (Unless there is a space in the input that I am failing to see.)

Comment: @WilliamPursell I understand OP's *"I need the number after the first space, so 3 and the number after it, 4 in a new variable"* to be a way of saying each digit in field two should be extracted and placed in one new variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the data in the buffer named 'input', it is pretty easy to parse as you describe:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int
main(void)
{
        char input[] = "45 34 RE 34";
        int three = 0;
        int four = 0;
        char *space;

        space = strchr(input, ' ');
        three = space[1] - '0';
        four = space[2] - '0';
        printf("%d:%d\n", three, four);
        return 0;
}
```

Note that you could use `scanf` to get the values, but `scanf` is a terrible tool for a beginner, and you would be better off playing with solutions like this to understand what is happening.

If you don't control the input, you will want to add bounds checking and ensure that `strchr` finds a value.

Answer (score 0):

> I need the number after the first space, so 3 and the number after it, 4 in a new variable.   ....   is there an easy code to do that?

Parse with `sscanf()` and use width limits

```
int number1, number2;
//                  vvvvv        Scan non-space characters and discard 
//                          vvv  Scan 1 digit int 
if (sscanf(input, "%*[^ ]%1d%1d", &number1, &number2) == 2) {
  printf("Success %d %d\n, number1, number2);
}
```

---

A more robust approach (above fails when first character is a space).

```
char *space = strchr(input, ' ');
if (space && sscanf(space, "%1d%1d", &number1, &number2) == 2) {
  printf("Success %d %d\n, number1, number2);
}
```